# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in subview

Tags: iphone, orientation, device

I'm having some trouble trying to change my view layout when rotation the device, I have my main view called OverviewViewController, this consists of 2 view that will be hidden / shown when the device is in a certain orientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
     // do some layout stuff
     NSLog(@"OverviewViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation");
     return YES;
}
```

Every time I rotate my device this method is executed twice, but in any subview it's never called, for instance;

```
// In OverviewViewController

_landscapeView = [[LandscapeOverviewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:_landscapeView.view];


// In LandscapeOverviewViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
    NSLog(@"LandscapeOverviewViewController: shouldAutorateToInterfaceOrientation");

    // Only change orientation when it's landscape
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Is there a reason for subviews not responding to the device orientation? The method is just never called there.

Comment: are you saying, on rotating, the overviewViewController calls the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method, but the LandscapeOverviewViewController doesnt call shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation ?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html

Comment: @calvinBhai That is exactly what I mean, yes.

Comment: @Luke, thanks for that, but it doesn't explain on how to fix it.

Comment: The method is executed twice 'cos on iOS5 there were some internal inconsistencies between rotation and presentation. i.e. it is called called before rotation AND presentation. On iOS6 this has been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see you are adding `LandscapeOverviewViewController` view as a subView to `self.view`.
 And you want your `LandscapeOverviewViewController`'s `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to be called which will never happen.
As these are called to that controller which are `pushed` or `presented` not like you are doing.

**Solution:**
You can do two things
1.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
     // do some layout stuff
     NSLog(@"OverviewViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation");
     //Call explicitly shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation of LandscapeOverviewViewController
     [_landscapeView shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
     return YES;
}
```

2. You can register the orientation notification in `LandscapeOverviewViewController`

Comment: Calling the method manually works fine, but is this a good way to do it?

Comment: Everything is good if it's working. But better way is registering the orientation change notification. And personally I have done the same in one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

is it required for you to use two separate viewcontrollers (one for each orientation) within your overviewViewController?

if you are just altering the frame values based on orientation, then make sure to use autoresizingmasks.

if not, just use separate views for each of the orientations, and hide unhide each view as required.

currently the problem is, your lanscapeViewController has no one sending it the viewControllerEvents.

with the current setup, you can present these view controllers modally, with this code in the OverviewViewController

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
{    
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [self presentModalViewController:LandscapeOverviewViewController animated: NO];
        }
    else{
       [self presentModalViewController:PortraitOverviewViewController animated: NO];
       }
}
```

Comment: The views are part of the layout and are completely different when the device is rotated, so I can't present them as a modalview

Comment: the documentation discourages this kind of processing in this method. shouldAutorotateToInterfactOrientation should only return yes/no as appropriate. Responding and changing should be done in the didRotate.. or other related protocols.

Comment: @DeanDavids you are right. instead of doing this in shouldAutoRotate, didRotate or willRotate methods can be used to do the same.

Comment: What is the correct method to trigger willRotateToInterfaceOrientation the first time your app launches?

Comment: I prefer not to trigger it manually. It should/will be called is when the device rotates, and before any changes happen to the UI.

Comment: @woutr_be: I break the actual work of laying out controls based on orientation into a separate method (layoutView) and then call it myself when the view is loaded, or when an orientation change happens.

Comment: @strings42 Thanks, I started doing that too lately